# Cannot Get Prop Of NextRequest

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

I'm trying to MiddleWare With Next.js's Middleware and JWT.

When I console.log `cookies` and `typeof cookies` variable im getting on console:

```js
{
  token: 'token='myToken'; Path=/'
}

object
```

Here is my code:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";

const SECRET = process.env.SECRET;

export function middleware(req, res) {
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  
  const url = req.url;
  
  if (url.includes("/admin")) {
      console.log(cookies)
      console.log(typeof cookies)
    
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

But when i try to get `token` prop like `cookies.token`, i got `undefined`

Any idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Funny Answer:

I just need to use get method for get specified prop

```js
const cookies = req.cookies.get('token');
```